# Building for multiple screen sizes

Tags: ios, constraints

One screen of my application involves displaying a form - asking the user to enter details which can be posted and saved eventually. In my form, I'm asking for the title, date, description, and attach any images. So there are `UILabels`, `UITextFields`, `UIButtons`, and `UITextView` involved. And they are displayed using interface builder + constraints.

Now as I view this screen on phones ranging from 8 to XR, I notice, for example in the XR, there is a lot of white space not being utilized. I understand the problem is due to my constraints. How do I adapt my constraints to help with this issue? So in the case of a longer screen such as an XR, my `UIViews` make use of the space provided rather than being bunched on the top half of the screen. I'm still a beginner w/iOS so I'm assuming it has to do something with constraints but not sure. How can I tackle this issue/change my approach when envisioning `iOS` applications?

Need some expert to enlighten me w/some iOS wisdom!

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand how autolayout and constraint works. After that you'll just need to create the UI ONCE in most cases and it will be good for all devices.

Since you're new I suggest putting one object(eg: UILabel) at a time and add constraints on it and see if it works before you add another object

Kindly see this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

and there are a lot of tutorial videos in youtube you can watch.

happy coding